# React Navigation - Custom Icon from AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation and for one of the icons of my tabBar, I would like to use an image that is stored in AsyncStorage. But the time it takes to get that image is too long and so the image is not rendered.. Where could I put my AsyncStorage.getItem in order for it to be ready to use in time by my tabNavigator ? I can't seem to find how to pass props to the TabNavigator, only to the screens with screenProps. Thanks !

Edit: 
Here is what I am doing so far :

// indexTab.js

```
class indexTab extends Component {

render() {
        return <Tabs />;
    }
}
```

// router.js

```
export const Tabs = TabNavigator (
{
(...)
Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => 
                <Image source={{uri: "'"+getImage()+"'"}} style={styles.icon}/>
    },
},
}, {    tabBarOptions: {
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: false,
        style: {
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            height: 70,
        },
        iconStyle : {
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            borderRadius: 50
        }
    }
},

async function getImage() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('id_photo').then((photo) => {
    var value = photo;
    return value;
})
```

}

I have done a test with two functions, one that returns the desired url, and the other (as above) that gets the url from asyncstorage; in the first case the icon renders and not in the second case, I think it means that the asyncstorage.getitem can't get the url before the tabs render

Comment: What do you mean by it takes too long? What is too long? What have you tried and researched so far? Also, please avoid asking multiple questions in a single post as mentioned in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have done a test with two functions, one that returns the desired url, and the other that gets the url from asyncstorage; in the first case the icon renders and not in the second case, I think it means that the asyncstorage.getitem can't get the url before the tabs render

Comment: And I have researched passing props to my tabNavigator or creating a global variable, it doesn't seem to work either way

Comment: Edit that information into your question along with code so it's easier for people to see what you've tried, what worked, what didn't. It will help others in the future with similar questions.

Comment: I added my code to be clearer, thanks for the feedback !

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem ! Instead of putting the two elements in two different files (I did it beacuase I found it in a tutorial) I actually put my Tabs const in the render of the indexTab class. Then you just need to put the AsyncStorage in your ComponenetDidMount and have a state for your url and a boolean state to force your return  to wait ! Here is my final code if anyone is interested :

```
class indexTab extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    image: null,
    isLoading: true
};
```

}

```
ComponentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('id_photo').then((photo) => {
        this.setState({ image: photo, isLoading: false})
        console.log(this.state.image);
    })
  }

render() {

  if (this.state.isLoading) {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
            <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      );
  }

  else {
    const Tabs = TabNavigator (
    {
      (...)
      Profile: {
        screen: Profile,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => 
              <Image source={{uri: this.state.image}} style={styles.icon}/>
        },
      },
    },  
    {
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
      tabBarOptions: {
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: false,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          height: 70,
        },
        iconStyle : {
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          borderRadius: 50
        },
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
      }
    },
    );

        return <Tabs />;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how do you keep the this.props.navigation.navigate('X') behavior? wrapping like this i just cannot navigate, its a noop, no error, no message.... its like if the function were out of context or something like that